# how do I suppress a inherited projects logback.xml file (2 logback.xml in a single project)?

Tags: logging, clojure, leiningen

I have project **com.samedhi/base** that has a **logback.xml** file and project **com.samedhi/derive** that also has a **logback.xml** file. Project '**derive**' has a dependency on '**base**'. When I "`lein trampoline repl`" on '**derive**', I get the following warning.

```
....
15:34:30,066 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
15:34:30,066 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
15:34:30,066 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/home/stephen/Work/com.samedhi/derive/client/config/logback.xml]
15:34:30,067 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs multiple times on the classpath.
15:34:30,067 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/home/stephen/.m2/repository/com/samedhi/base.app/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/base.app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/logback.xml]
15:34:30,067 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [file:/home/stephen/Work/com.samedhi/derive/client/config/logback.xml]
15:34:30,129 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
....
```

So, the problem appears to be that I have two logback.xml's in my classpath. What am I supposed to do to "surpress" the logback.xml from project '**base**' when I lein repl from the '**derive**' project?

Comment: In my case I want to create a general logging library that my team uses in all projects so I want my logback.xml buried in our logging util dependency.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, you should never package a logging config file (logback.xml, log4j.properties, or what have you) inside a JAR file. The whole point of even having a logging config file is to make it easy for the end-user to adjust logging levels by editing the file. Burying it in an archive defeats the purpose of that, because to change the logging level your user has to expand the archive, edit the file, and then re-package the archive.

Here's my preferred layout for a deployed application. It's a little bit more work to set up, but IMO is worth the trouble because it gives you the flexibility and ease of configuration that an uberjar doesn't.

```
my-app/
  bin/
    run-app.sh
  config/
    logback.xml
  lib/
    my-lib.jar
    my-app.jar
```

Your `run-app.sh` script would look something like:

```
BIN=`dirname "$0"`
BASE=$BIN/..
java -cp "$BASE/config:$BASE/lib/*" my-app.main
```

This has the advantage that, by putting the config directory at the front of the classpath, any logging config file found there should take precedence over anything that might be found in one of the JARs (e.g. included by a third-party library that you have no control over).

Comment: +1 for the general recommendation to not package a logging config file in a jar. The only times that we do package the logging file are when creating an executable jar or [java webstart release](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25001350/how-do-i-specify-a-logback-configuration-for-use-in-a-java-webstart-application). However, as we use maven, we have to do a subsequent `mvn clean install` to remove the jar with the logging configuration from the local repository.

Answer (score 3):

In case the **base** is a library it should not come with a logback.xml. Why is a library concerned about logging? In case it is an application, you should probably extract the common part into a library – **base-common** – and a small application – **base-app**. Then **base-common** does not contain any logback configuration. **base-app** and **derive** both depend on **base-common**. They can specify their logback configuration without conflict.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to answer my own question because I was specifically asking in the context of Clojure (although I completely failed to mention that in originating question, genius).

I fixed the problem by doing as Alex (accepted answer) suggest, and putting my logback.xml in its own special directory `dev-config`. I then use clojure's `project.clj` file to specify that `dev-config` should only be loaded when the development profile is run, as follows:

```
;; project.clj
(defproject com.samedhi/base.app "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]]
  :profiles {:dev {:source-paths ["dev", "dev-config"]}}
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0"
  :source-paths ["app/src" "app/templates"]
  :resource-paths ["config"]
  :target-path "out/"
  :compiler-options {:externs ["app/externs/base.js"]}
  :aliases {"dumbrepl" ["trampoline" "run" "-m" "clojure.main/main"]})
```

The only important point is that **:profiles => :dev => :source-paths** has had "dev-config" added to its vector. This directory is picked up when I am doing local development, but is not part of created jar files, and as such does not show up in other projects that import this project. So, the logging shows up when doing development on this project, but does not show up when this project is used by other projects. Excellent.

Answer (score 1):

I found the Alex strategy to be effective. I would like to add a small hint: you can create a common-config project with the *editable common configuration files* put inside (e.g. logback.xml etc.) Add the resulting artifact as a dependency in all your projects, with the scope *provided*.
This will allow you to use the logback.xml at compile/test time (from Eclipse or whatever IDE), but will exclude the common-config jar from the dependencies available for inheritance. At runtime you will provide the proper file (depending on the dev/test/prod environment) as Alex shows.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I modified the answer from Stephen, so `project.clj` looks like so:

```
:profiles {:dev {:resource-paths ["test/resources"]}}  ; appended to default
```

and the new directory `test/resources` contains the `logback.xml` used for testing the library, but it is not propogated to users of the lib.

Note that, as per the comment, `"test/resources"` is appended to the default value of `:resources-paths` to create a final value of `["resources" "test/resources"]`

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, I couldn't get away from this problem with how I built my jars. I instead found this in the [doc](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#logback.statusLC):

```
-Dlogback.statusListenerClass=ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener
```